# MySQL Prosedural Language 1

Tags: mysql

SQL query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE tree_add_node(IN id int(11), IN name varchar(50), IN label varchar(50))
BEGIN
DECLARE lft_value int(11), rht_value int(11), lvl_value int(11);
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT `lft` INTO lft_value FROM trees WHERE `tree_id`=id;
SELECT `rht` INTO rht_value FROM trees WHERE `tree_id`=id;
SELECT `lvl` INTO lvl_value FROM trees WHERE `tree_id`=id;
UPDATE `trees` SET `tree_id`=`tree_id` +1,`description`='null',`lft`=`lft`+2,`rht`=`rht`+2 WHERE `tree_id`>= id;
INSERT INTO `trees`(`tree_id`, `name`, `label`, `description`, `lft`, `rht`, `lvl`) VALUES (id,'name','label',NULL,lft_value,rht_value,lvl_value)
COMMIT;
END;
```

MySQL said:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near ' rht_value int(11), lvl_value int(11); START TRANSACTION; SELECT
`lft` INTO lf' at line 3
```

Comment: Look at your code properly. It's a syntax error. And simply copy pasting the code with no explanation whatsoever won't help you at all.

Comment: if i can found my error then i was not post it

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-local-variable.html

Answer (score 0):

There are some error in your procedure

1) you declare 3 variables and define datatype to all in one declare statement that is error.
[sol] define one datatype to one declare statement

```
Use this :- DECLARE lft_value , rht_value , lvl_value int(11);
```

2) Forget semicolon after insert query

```
[sol] INSERT INTO `trees`(`tree_id`, `name`, `label`, `description`,   `lft`, `rht`, `lvl`) VALUES (id,'name','label',NULL,lft_value,rht_value,lvl_value);

CREATE PROCEDURE tree_add_node(IN id int(11), IN name varchar(50), IN label varchar(50))
BEGIN
DECLARE lft_value , rht_value , lvl_value int(11);
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT `lft` INTO lft_value FROM trees WHERE `tree_id`=id;
SELECT `rht` INTO rht_value FROM trees WHERE `tree_id`=id;
SELECT `lvl` INTO lvl_value FROM trees WHERE `tree_id`=id;
UPDATE `trees` SET `tree_id`=`tree_id` +1,`description`='null',`lft`=`lft`+2,`rht`=`rht`+2 WHERE `tree_id`>= id;
INSERT INTO `trees`(`tree_id`, `name`, `label`, `description`, `lft`, `rht`, `lvl`) VALUES (id,'name','label',NULL,lft_value,rht_value,lvl_value);
COMMIT;
END;
```